# SOQL query exclude null values in apex class

Tags: apex, soql, json

We have following values:

---

```
|Id  | Name  |Language|
|1   | abc   |        |
```

When I query the above record and debug this record in apex class it shows:-

```
(Library__c:{Id=xxxxxxxxxxxx, Name=abc})
```

It is not showing language field Why?

Actually, I need to create JSON from the query result. As the query result not showing the null or empty values, therefore, Json is also not including the null and empty values.

Comment: Post your SOQL query that you are using.

Comment: Query is Select id,name from Library__c where id='xxxxxxx'

Comment: In above query you have not mentioned Language field.

Comment: Query is Select id,name,Language__c from Library__c where id='xxxxxxx'

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```
list<Map<String, Object>> aa = new list<Map<String, Object>> ();
SObject[] b = [Select id, name, Language__c from Library__c];

for (SObject b : sobjects) {
    Map<String, Object> a = new Map<String, Object> ();
    for (SObjectField f : account.sobjecttype.getdescribe().fields.getmap().values()) {
        try { a.put(String.valueOf(f), b.get(f)); }
        catch(Exception e) { a.put(String.valueOf(f), null); }
    }
    aa.add(a);
}
System.debug(json.serialize(aa));
```

If you don't want all the non-query'd fields to be null values in your json you can adjust the list of Sobjectfield returned by the describe.

If it's just the language field you wan't to check you can do the following:

```
list<Map<String, Object>> aa = new list<Map<String, Object>> ();
SObject[] b = [Select id, name, Language__c from Library__c];

for (SObject b : sobjects) {
    Map<String, Object> a = new Map<String, Object> ();
    try { a.put('Language__c', b.get('Language__c')); }
    catch(Exception e) { a.put('Language__c', null); }
    aa.add(a);
}
System.debug(json.serialize(aa));
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,`System.debug` does not print fields with null value but I will be glad to be wrong about this.I am not able to find any documentation to support this but I tried this in my org and the debug doesn't print null field.

Comment: I think it is not because of `System.debug`. I think that SOQL not returns nothing when every object found has null in queried field. And this causes described Issue.

Comment: SOQL returns the field even when they are null.It's just that they are not shown in debug @pepper42

Comment: Any proofs for this?

Comment: if the field is not mentioned in SOQL and you use it in apex, you get an error

Comment: Yes SOQL return the field but not shown in System.debug. Also when I try to make Jason from the SOQL query result. The fields with NULL values are not including in Jason.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a wrapper for Your Json object and then assign the values from objects from query to wrappers, then You will always have values or null.

I think that SOQL not returns nothing when every object found has null in queried field. And this causes described Issue.