# JSON serialize SObject including fields with null values

Tags: apex, json, sobject, serialize

I've currently got a use case where I would like to JSON serialize an SObject, but include fields with null (blank) values.

According to the documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm), using `JSON.serialize(objectToSerialize, suppressApexObjectNulls)` should give me the option to suppress null values or not. But it doesn't seem to be the case for SObjects. Take this example:

```
Account account = [SELECT Id, Name, AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE Id = '001b000000Irj49'];
system.debug(JSON.serialize(account, false));
```

Returns:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "type": "Account",
    "url": "\/services\/data\/v42.0\/sobjects\/Account\/001b000000Irj49AAB"
  },
  "Id": "001b000000Irj49AAB",
  "Name": "Ben"
}
```

Where the AccountNumber field for my test record is null, but I would actually like it to be in my JSON.

However, if I run:

```
Account account = new Account(Name = 'Ben', AccountNumber = null);
system.debug(JSON.serialize(account, false));
```

I get:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "type": "Account"
  },
  "Name": "Ben",
  "AccountNumber": null
}
```

So it seems like I would only get a null value if I explicitly assign null to the SObject.

Obviously I can iterate over each field in the object and build the JSON structure that way, but I would prefer to keep it a simple one line. My other test case is using a wrapper class, which seems to work when toggling `suppressApexObjectNulls`.

Comment: Hi there. We don't use some types of markdown here; notably the triple-backtick syntax is not typically used because it's harder to read. In the future, please use the `{}` button for proper formatting.

Comment: Might help you [SOQL query exclude null values in apex class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170564/soql-query-exclude-null-values-in-apex-class)

Comment: soql query excludes null values and the result from soql will only contain the non-null values. You are serializing the result from soql.so you will not have any null values in the "account" variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the Apex Dev Guide, **Starting with API version 28.0, null fields aren’t serialized and aren’t included in the JSON string, unlike in earlier versions. This change doesn’t affect deserializing JSON strings with JSON methods, such as deserialize(jsonString, apexType). This change is noticeable when you inspect the JSON string.**

The sample code below explains the difference between the results obtained for content queried via SOQL using API v27.0 and earlier versus its later versions.

```
String jsonString = JSON.serialize(
                 [SELECT Id, Name, Website FROM Account WHERE Website = null LIMIT 1]);
System.debug(jsonString);

// In v27.0 and earlier, the string includes the null field and looks like the following.
// {"attributes":{...},"Id":"001D000000Jsm0WIAR","Name":"Acme","Website":null}

// In v28.0 and later, the string doesn’t include the null field and looks like 
//  the following.
// {"attributes":{...},"Name":"Acme","Id":"001D000000Jsm0WIAR"}}
```

This implies, you will need to write a custom wrapper based or `getGlobalDescribe()` based logic to include null values within your serialized Json.

Refer the following link  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm to understand this.

Comment: If you're going to cite a resource, please link to it and include the relevant passage as text.

Comment: If you include just the link and none of the text, the answer still is not as useful.